# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

Thanks @Alexis for the editing! =)

Hello this is my first call to help, I'm new to python and trying to make an insert in a mysql db, but can not manage to succeed... any ideas?
Many thanks in advance,
L

---

this is the code:

```
insert_query = ("insert into mydb.Ticker_Value "

"(Ticker_name, Ticker_Value_date, Ticker_Value_high, Ticker_Value_low, Ticker_Value_open, Ticker_Value_close, Ticker_Value_volume) "

"VALUES (", Save_tckr, Save_date, float(Save_high[0]), float(Save_low[0]), float(Save_open[0]), float(Save_close[0]), float(Save_volume[0]), ")")

        print (insert_query)
        cursor_ins.execute(insert_query) #-- he aquí los problemas
```

---

this is the result:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/luciano/PycharmProjects/finance_marketplace/extract.py

 File "/Users/luciano/PycharmProjects/finance_marketplace/extract.py", line 74, in <module>

('insert into mydb.Ticker_Value (Ticker_name, Ticker_Value_date, Ticker_Value_high, Ticker_Value_low, Ticker_Value_open, Ticker_Value_close, Ticker_Value_volume) VALUES (', u'A', '2015-11-27', 42.2, 41.16, 41.32, 41.97, 1935738.0, ')')

   cursor_ins.execute(insert_query) #-- this is what gives me the creeps! =)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 492, in execute
stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `insert_query`is a tuple. You have to concatenate elements into one string using `+`